# Azure Logic App Receive Image HTTP Trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-triggers

I'm trying to create a logic app that is triggered from an HTTP POST where I send it an image. What would my JSON schema look like when setting up the HTTP trigger assuming I have image "picture1.jpg"?

Do I need to POST the image to my Logic App as a stream?

Comment: @mitch-stewart would be the prefered approach, otherwise you can encode your image stream to base64 to pass it in the body

Answer (score 0):

Rather than POST the image directly to the Azure Logic App endpoint, I'd upload the image to Azure Blob Storage and use this as the trigger. Here's a helpful [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) outlining trigger creation.